# Modify UoBLab.cls font letter

Tags: fonts

does someone know who can I modify this [template](https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uob-lab-report-template/nqvcmksshmny) to put the same letter in all the text of the document (Helvetica if possible).

Thank you so much for all.

Comment: You might add [these lines](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyreheros/) of code to your preamble and see if that works. Or, if the template loads `fontspec`, add `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}`.

Comment: Thanks @Davislor it works perfect! :D

Comment: Since it worked, I’ve made my comment an answer, since we’re not really supposed to answer in the comments. I’d appreciate if you’d accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as an answer, since it worked for you:

You want to use TeX Gyre Heros, the clone of Helvetica that ships with TeX.  In PDFTeX, the code for this is,

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If your document uses `fontspec`, you instead want:

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
```

Comment: For sure I'll accept you answer!